# HOW can i write the following statements through loop in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, maps, activeadmin

```
 CmsService::SearchContentPractiseProblems.form_fields.each do |field|
          if field[:key].to_s === "answer_a"
              row field[:key] do
                content['answers']['answer_a']
              end
          elsif field[:key].to_s === "answer_b"
              row field[:key] do
                content['answers']['answer_b']
              end
          elsif field[:key].to_s === "answer_c"
              row field[:key] do
                content['answers']['answer_c']
              end
          elsif field[:key].to_s === "answer_d"
              row field[:key] do
                content['answers']['answer_d']
              end
          else
            row field[:key] do
              content[field[:key].to_s]
            end
          end
```

here i want to write the following if elsif through loops but I am stucked to get the solution can somebody help me in that

my form field is:

```
 def self.form_fields
   [
    { key: :code, label: "Code"},
    { key: :ordering, label: "Ordering"},
    { key: :content, label: "Practise Question", editable: true},
    { key: :answer_a, label: "Answer A", editable: true},
    { key: :answer_b, label: "Answer B", editable: true},
    { key: :answer_c, label: "Answer C", editable: true},
    { key: :answer_d, label: "Answer D", editable: true},
    { key: :explaination, label: "Answer Exp.", editable: true}
  ]
end
```

and the response that I want after processingg is

```
{     
    "code": "ascending-order-pq-1",
    "content": "Arrange the following numbers in ascending order.\n22, 2322, 2222, 222",
    "ordering": 1,
    "answers": {
        "answer_b": "22 < 222 < 2222 < 2322",
        "answer_a": "22 < 222 < 2322 < 2222",
        "answer_d": "2322 < 2222 < 222 < 22",
        "answer_c": "22 < 2222 < 222 < 2322"
    },
    "correct": "answer_b",
    "explaination": "While comparing multi-digit numbers, the numbers with the least number of digits come first. For multi-digit numbers with the same number of digits, we compare digits from left to right."
}
```

Comment: Maybe `answers = ['answer_a', 'answer_b', 'answer_c', 'answer_d']; f = field[:key].to_s; if answers.include?(f); row field[:key] { content['answers'][f] }; else; row field[:key] { content[field[:key].to_s }; end`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should compact to this:

```rb
CmsService::SearchContentPractiseProblems.form_fields.each do |field|
  answer_fields = %w[answer_a answer_b answer_c answer_d]

  row field[:key] do
    key = field[:key].to_s
    if answer_fields.include?(key)
      content['answers'][key]
    else
      content[key]
    end
  end
end
```

Please test it.

`%w[a b c]` is equivalent to `["a", "b", "c"]` in Ruby

`if-else-end` control structure just returns something at the end of the day, so

```rb
row field[:key] do
  if condition
    something
  else
    something_else
  end
end
```

is equivalent to

```rb
if condition
  row field[:key] do
    something
  end
else
  row field[:key] do
    something_else
  end
end
```

but the first one is more compact and less error-prone

Comment: thanks this is working for me after trying a lot of stuffs